# pyspark register built-in function and use in spark.sql query

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What is the right way to register and use a `pyspark version 3.1.2` built-in function in a `spark.sql` query?

Below is a minimal example to create a `pyspark` DataFrame object and run a simple query in pure SQL.

An attempt at code to run the same query with a `pyspark` built-in function errors with `...TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: -5 of type <class 'int'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function...`

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# spark session and create spark DataFrame from pandas DataFrame
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set('spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled', 'true')
pdf = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'y': [-5, -6, -7, -8]})
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')

# pure SQL
rv1 = spark.sql(f'SELECT ABS(x + y) AS z FROM df').toPandas()

# pyspark built-in function
spark.udf.register('abs_builtin', F.abs, T.LongType())
rv2 = spark.sql(f'SELECT abs_builtin(x + y) AS z FROM df').toPandas()
```

Comment: A python function with a lambda works: `spark.udf.register('abs_builtin',lambda a,b : abs(a+b), T.LongType())`

Comment: confirm the lambda function works, but will there be a performance improvement if the built-in function is somehow used.  another approach that also works is ```pandas_udf```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution without the built-in function is to use a `pandas_udf`

```
import numpy as np
@F.pandas_udf(returnType=T.LongType())
def abs_pandas_udf(x: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return np.abs(x)
spark.udf.register('abs_pandas_udf', abs_pandas_udf)
rv3 = spark.sql(f'SELECT abs_pandas_udf(x + y) AS z FROM df').toPandas()
```

Answer (score 0):

pyspark builtin standard functions expect Column (pyspark.sql.Column) type as parameter, whereas user-defined functions expect primitive and complex types (based on function definition). That's why your implementation is failing.

UDFs are recommended only when there is no option.

Comment: How to write it so does not fail?

Comment: As you've mentioned in the question, the pure SQL way is the way to go!! built-in standard functions are more or less the same functions we use in SQL..